# Terminate TCP Connetions using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, tcp, server

I require a command to terminate a single open TCP connection. I've looked through several forums and I can't see to get a clear answer with out having to download 3rd party tools.

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    10.0.0.0:59614          SSHServer1:ssh      ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.0.0.0:59648          SSHServer2:ssh      ESTABLISHED
```

The goal is to enumerate a single value from this:

```
$ConnectionToKill = netstat | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'ServerSSH1' | ConvertFrom-String | Select-Object p4
```

And use the variable $ConnectionToKill to close the connection

Comment: [`Get-NetTcpConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/tcpip/get-nettcpconnection) outputs an [`MSFT_NetTCPConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872450(v=vs.85).aspx) which has a `RequestStateChange()` Method, but I'm not sure if this fits your needs.

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply @Clijsters. How would I be able to use that method RequestStateChange() to terminate an open TCP connection?